# trouble using "while" loop to fill array with binary

Tags: java, arrays

It's my first time posting here. Ive been stumped on this program for many hours now. I've scoured the web and found only small bits of code that gave me more insight, but I'm confused. Its supposed to make binary.

The program runs but seems to return only 3 integers in "reverse" binary with the 4th or more always being "0" indicating the array field is empty. Anybody know whats going on?

```
/** 
* A program that prints the binary digits of a positive integer
*
* @author Your Name
* @version Today's Date
*/
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintBinaryFixed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int MIN = 0;
        final int MAX = (int) (Math.pow(2, 30) - 1);
        int[] digits = new int[30]; // array to hold the digits

        int number = readInput("Enter an integer from " + MIN + " to " + MAX, MIN, MAX); // number to divide


        // Your code goes here. This code must do the following:
        // Declare a "companion" variable to count how many digits stored
        // Initialize that variable appropriately
        // While number > 0
        // Store the remainder (number % 2) in the array
        // Update the companion variable
        // Set number to be number / 2
        // Display the filled portion of the array in reverse order
        // System.out.println(number);
        int index = 0; // the counter
        int q = number / 2; // quotient
        int r = number % 2; // remainder
        int n = 1; // iteration
        int qr = 0; // returning quotient


        while (number > 0) {

            number = (int) q;
            // System.out.println(number);
            // System.out.println("Quotient - "+q);
            System.out.println("Remainder - " + r);
            // System.out.println("Iteration - "+n);

            qr = (int) q / 2; // Quotient to be returned
            r = (int) q % 2; // New Remainder to be returned
            q = qr; // Resetting the number to be divided
            // n++; // Incrementing the loop

            digits[index] = r;
            index++;

        }

        listBackwardsFrom(digits, index);
    }

    /**
     * Print the contents of an array backwards, starting from index last
     * 
     * @param array:
     *            an array of integers
     * @param last:
     *            the index of the starting location
     */
    public static void listBackwardsFrom(int[] array, int last) {
        for (int i = 0; i < last; i++) {
            //System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            //System.out.println(array[28]);
            //System.out.println(array[27]);
            //System.out.println(array[26]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read in an integer between two given bounds
     * 
     * @param prompt:
     *            the prompt to show the user
     * @param min:
     *            the smallest acceptable input value
     * @param max:
     *            the largest acceptable input value
     */
    public static int readInput(String prompt, int min, int max) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean check = true;
        System.out.println(prompt);
        String userinput = scan.next();
        while (check) {

            try {

                if (Integer.valueOf(userinput) <= max && Integer.valueOf(userinput) >= min) {
                    check = false;
                } else {
                    check = true;
                    System.out.println("enter an integer in valid range");
                    userinput = scan.next();

                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                check = true;
                System.out.println("enter a valid integer");
                userinput = scan.next();
            }

        }

        return Integer.parseInt(userinput);

    }

    /**
     * Read in a positive integer and return its value
     * 
     * @param the
     *            prompt to be shown to the user
     */
    public static int readInteger(String prompt) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean check = true;
        System.out.println(prompt);
        String userinput = scan.next();
        while (check) {

            try {

                if (Integer.valueOf(userinput) > 0) {
                    check = false;
                } else {
                    check = true;
                    System.out.println("enter a valid integer");
                    userinput = scan.next();

                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                check = true;
                System.out.println("enter a valid integer");
                userinput = scan.next();
            }

        }

        return Integer.parseInt(userinput);
    }
}
```

Comment: debug your code

Comment: Sorry, questions of the form "Here's my code, what's wrong" are off-topic.  You should have already stepped through the code in the debugger and be able to identify what is behaving unexpectedly.  Please visit the [help] and especially read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

check this, store the reminder before calculating next cycle.

```
        while (number > 0) {
        number = (int) q;
        System.out.println("Remainder - " + r);
        digits[index] = r;
        qr = (int) q / 2; // Quotient to be returned
        r = (int) q % 2; // New Remainder to be returned
        q = qr; // Resetting the number to be divided
        index++;
    }
```

and traverse from the end to start.

```
public static void listBackwardsFrom(int[] array, int last) {
    for (int i = last-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! It was because i was storing the reminder after calculating the cycle. It works now!  also my for loop was a little dusty but I understand now. thanks again